# How to get variable between two charaters in PowerShell?

Tags: string, powershell, split

I have a PowerShell script that gets part of a string between `>`and `<`:

```
$splitArray = "SomeText>MyVariable<SomeMoreText" -split ">",0
$string = $splitArray[1] -split "<",0
$MyVariable = $string[0]
```

Is there a more efferent way of getting the `MyVariable` between the `> <`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex replace:

```
$myVar = "SomeText>MyVariable<SomeMoreText" -replace '.+>(.+)<.+', '$1'
```

Comment: You could also do it as a straight regex match as well. I just like the way the replace looks better as code. If you want to see the match method I can post that too.

Comment: That works great thanks, could you explain the `'$1'` in the replace cmd?

Comment: As I understand it, by trying it out just now,  
you find the variable and you ask powershell to replace the content of the first match with the contents of the first grouped match. 

So your entire line matches the regex expression and gets replaced by the variable which was put in the first group.

Comment: That pretty much sums it up.